Python: mongodb to geopandas
I'm working with a MongoDB database containing city polygon data. I've successfully connected to it from Python and downloaded the data. However, when I convert it into a GeoDataFrame, the geometry column doesn't seem to be recognized correctly. How can I ensure GeoPandas can utilize the geometry data?
The following code demonstrates the process:
query = {
    'properties.PROVINCIA': 'Ciudad'
}
consult = collection.find(query)
df_result = pd.DataFrame(consult)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_result['properties'].tolist())
df['geometry'] = df_result['geometry']
df.head()

Output:


Edit your question and add - as text - the value of geometry. Since that needs to be modified to match GeoPandas' expected structure. Also, see this answer for an example of how to convert before loading it as DataFrame.

I think you need to use a geopandas.GeoDataFrame()
Something like this:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df_result['properties'].tolist())
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(data=df, geometry=df_result['geometry'])


I have no experience in converting data from MongoDB to GeoPandas ... but I would try to replace pd.DataFrame.from_records() with geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_records().
